# c/c++ Controlling Linux service in my app

Tags: c++, c, linux, service

I want to start or stop mariadb in my app.
So, I am just using

```
system("systemctl start mariadb.service");
```

But it does not work.

Error is:

> Error creating textual authentication agent: Error opening current controlling terminal for the process (`/dev/tty'): No such device or address (polkit-error-quark, 0)

What should I do?

My app runs with root and daemon
Thanks.

Comment: What do you think the `system` call does? What do you think the error means?

Comment: Are you using VirtualBox by any chance?

Comment: Perhaps, it needs terminal (tty) for some reason? For example, it may want to ask for sudo password, but there is no stdin. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339645/280408

Comment: I'm not using VirtualBox. And I don't know the error means. But @VictorIstomin you are right. I'm using setsid(); before system call. Because it runs with daemon. I test variable method and finally I erase setsid(); Now it works. thanks.